# Commuting Limit and Integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, power-series

Say that $X$ is a real-valued random variable with expectation zero and variance $\sigma^2$. Suppose, as in [Bernstein's inequality](http://www.stat.math.ethz.ch/~geer/empirical-processes.pdf), that 
$$E|X|^m\leq \frac{m!}{2}K^{m-2}\sigma^2~(m=2,3,\dots).$$
Then does it hold that for all $0<\lambda<1/K$, we have
$$E(\exp(\lambda X))=1+\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\lambda^mE(X^m)?$$

**What I have so far:**

The claim above was the first step in van de Geer's proof of Bernstein's inequality. I know that if $\lambda_0>0$ is such that $E(\exp(\lambda X))<\infty$ for all $|\lambda|<\lambda_0$, then we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to get
$$E(\exp(\lambda X))=1+\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\lambda^mE(X^m).$$
However, I'm concerned whether we can pick a $\lambda_0>1/K$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is centered, the following equality holds:
$$\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\lambda X \right)   \right]  -1= 
\mathbb E\left[\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{m=2}^N\frac{\left(\lambda X\right)^m}{m!}                     \right]  $$
We would like to exchange the limit with the integral. Let 
$Y_N:=\sum_{m=2}^N\frac{\left(\lambda X\right)^m}{m!} $. Then $Y_N\to e^{\lambda X}-1-X$ almost everywhere and $\left\lvert Y_N\right\rvert\leqslant \sum_{m=2}^{ +\infty}   \frac{\left\lvert  \lambda X\right\rvert ^m}{m!}=:Y$. Condition 
$$\mathbb  E|X|^m\leqslant \frac{m!}{2}K^{m-2}\sigma^2~(m=2,3,\dots)$$
combined with $0<\lambda<1/K$
guarantee integrability of $Y$.